# Bash script of unzipping unknown name files

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, unzip, glob

I have a folder that after an rsync will have a zip in it. I want to unzip it to its own folder(if the zip is L155.zip, to unzip its content to  L155 folder). The problem is that I dont know it's name beforehand(although i know it will be "letter-number-number-number"), so I have to unzip an uknown file to its unknown folder and this to be done automatically.

The command “unzip *”(or unzip *.zip) works in terminal, but not in a script.
These are the commands that have worked through terminal one by one, but dont work in a script.

```
#!/bin/bash
unzip * #also tried .zip and /path/to/file/*  when script is on different folder
i=$(ls | head -1)
y=${i:0:4}
mkdir $y
unzip * -d $y
```

First I unzip the file, then I read the name of the first extracted file through ls and save it in a variable.I take the first 4 chars and make a directory with it and then again unzip the files to that specific folder.

The whole procedure after first unzip is done, is because the files inside .zip, all start with a name that the zip already has, so if L155.ZIP is the zip, the files inside with be L155*****.txt.

The zip file is at `/path/to/file/NAME.zip`. 
When I run the script I get errors like the following:

```
unzip: cannot find or open /path/to/file/*.ZIP
unzip: cannot find or open /path/to/file//*.ZIP.zip
unzip: cannot find or open /path/to/file//*.ZIP.ZIP. No zipfiles found. 
mkdir: cannot create directory 'data': File exists data 
unzip: cannot find or open data, data.zip or data.ZIP.
```

Comment: You should try to be more specific than "doesn't work". What does this mean? Does it produce an error message? If so, what is the message? Does it do something unexpected? If so, what does it do and how did it differ from your expectations?

Comment: Well, at first when trying to execute the script, i get "unzip:  cannot find or open /path/to/file/*.ZIP, /path/to/file//*.ZIP.zip or /path/to/file//*.ZIP.ZIP.  No zipfiles found.
mkdir: cannot create directory `data': File exists
data
unzip:  cannot find or open data, data.zip or data.ZIP.". Hope its better now :)

Comment: Kyle Kanos, that doesn't seem to work, or I do something wrong.

Comment: @user2809595: It doesn't matter where the script is stored. What matters is the current working directory when you invoke the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following.

```
for i in *.[Zz][Ii][Pp]; do
    DIRECTORY=$(basename "$i" .zip)
    DIRECTORY=$(basename "$DIRECTORY" .ZIP)
    unzip "$i" -d "$DIRECTORY"
done
```

As noted, the basename program removes the indicated suffix `.zip` from the filename provided.

I have edited it to be case-insensitive. Both `.zip` and `.ZIP` will be recognized.

Comment: There is no difference between `$(find *.zip)` and `*.zip` except that the former will not do what you want if there is a directory named `something.zip`, and it will chew up a lot more resources. Both of them will fail in annoying ways if there is a zipfile with spaces in its name.

Comment: This one gives "find: `*.zip': No such file or directory". The script is on the same folder with .zip

Comment: @forensick: Your problem is not with unzip, then. Put `pwd` as the first command in your script and see what directory it is searching.

Comment: s:~/data$ ./yourscript.sh

/home/manolis/data
find: `*.zip': No such file or directory
Data is the folder that holds both the script and the .zip

Comment: You were correct, the problem was that the file ends in .ZIP and not in .zip. Now that i corrected that, i get "Archive:  K197.ZIP
checkdir:  cannot create extraction directory: K197.ZIP
           File exists
"

Comment: It is working correctly now (changed zip to ZIP) and it doesnt need the mkdir command. Thanks! It also worked as rici recommended "/path/to/thescript.sh /path/to/data_directory"

Comment: @dangenet, at the risk of beating a dead horse, I'd just like to point out that `$(find *.[zZ][iI][pP] -type f)` will be glob-expanded *before* the find ever happens, resulting in something like `$(find foo.zip bar.Zip -type f)`. Consequently, you might just as well have said `for i in *.[zZ][iI][pP]; do` (or, if you worried about directories being in the list, `for i in *.[zZ][iI][pP]; do if [[ -f $i ]]; then`; `find` is not helping you in the slightest. But both of those will fail if there are spaces in a zip filename, because either way the list of filenames will be split at whitespace.

Comment: @rici: you're right and I'll edit my answer. `find` merely told me his problem wasn't `unzip`. Re whitespace, `find . -iname *.zip -exec unzip {} +` is case insensitive and should handle whitespace, right? but it doesn't create the directory.

Comment: @dangenet: right. The way to do it is something like this: `arr=(*.zip); for file in "${arr[@]}"; do ...`. It would be really cool if you could just put the parenthesized array expression directly into the `for` statement, but you can't and I don't believe that it is even being considered.

Answer (score 2):

**Original answer**

Supposing that `foo.zip` contains a folder `foo`, you could simply run

```
#!/bin/bash
unzip \*.zip \*
```

And then run it as `bash auto-unzip.sh`.

If you want to have these files extracted into a different folder, then I would modify the above as

```
#!/bin/bash
cp *.zip /home/user
cd /home/user
unzip \*.zip \*
rm *.zip
```

This, of course, you would run from the folder where all the zip files are stored.

---

**Another answer**

Another "simple" fix is to get [dtrx](http://brettcsmith.org/2007/dtrx/) (also available in the Ubuntu repos, possibly for other distros). This will extract each of your `*.zip` files into its own folder. So if you want the data in a different folder, I'd follow the second example and change it thusly:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp *.zip /home/user
cd /home/user
dtrx *.zip
rm *.zip
```

Comment: Should this be inside the folder of the zip? I mean, i have the .zip file inside /home/user/data folder and the script at /home/user. Then i have to run another script with the other commands?

Comment: Kyle, how is that different from `unzip '*.zip'`? Surely the wildcard specification `*` just means "all the files", which is the default if you don't specify a pattern? Also, that only works if the zipfile was created with the correct top-level folder name.

Comment: @rici: (1) do you expect it to be different? (2) was this mentioned by anyone else in this question? (3) was it specified in the OP that the files would be going to somewhere other than the top-level folder? Answers: No. No. No. And so your problem is.....?

Comment: @forensick: I am adjusting my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: In response to (3), that's how I interpreted "I want to unzip it to its own folder (if the zip is L155.zip, to unzip its content to L155 folder)?" And, (2) all the other answers use the `-d` option to accomplish that precise task. Obviously, it would be easier if the zip files were created with the folder structure in the first placre.

Comment: @rici: $1 says you did not actually test my answer. Had you done so, you would have seen that each `*.zip` file is indeed put into its own folder. Instead, you merely commented because my answer did not conform to your own personal & arbitrary standards. Perhaps it is your MO to **not** test your answers, but I think that SO should not be a collection of "ought to work" answers, but a collection of "this **will** work" answers.

Comment: On the contrary, I did test your answer because I'd love to have a simple way to unzip without polluting the directory I'm in. Here's what I did: `mkdir test && cd test; touch a b c d e f; zip foo.zip a b c; rm a b c; unzip \*.zip \*; echo $(find . | sort)`. At this point, if it solved the OP, I would see `./d ./e ./f ./foo ./foo.zip ./foo/a ./foo/b ./foo/c`. But what I see is `./a ./b ./c ./d ./e ./f ./foo.zip`. No directory was created. Perhaps your `unzip` is different from mine. `unzip -v` reports `UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.`

Comment: @rici: Aha. My solutions supposes that `foo.zip` contains a folder `/foo` and yours doesn't. I will fix my answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @KyleKanos: `dtrx` seems like a good solution. And apology accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

If the folder has only file file with the extension `.zip`, you can extract the name without an extension with the `basename` tool:

```
BASE=$(basename *.zip .zip)
```

This will produce an error message if there is more than one file matching `*.zip`.

Just to be clear about the issue here, the assumption is that the zip file does not contain a folder structure. If it did, there would be no problem; you could simply extract it into the subfolders with `unzip`. The following is only needed if your zipfile contains loose files, and you want to extract them into a subfolder.

With that caveat, the following should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR=${1:-.}
BASE=$(basename "$DIR/"*.zip .zip 2>/dev/null) ||
  { echo More than one zipfile >> /dev/stderr; exit 1; }
if [[ $BASE = "*" ]]; then
  echo No zipfile found >> /dev/stderr
  exit 1
fi
mkdir -p "$DIR/$BASE" ||
  { echo Could not create $DIR/$BASE >> /dev/stderr; exit 1; }
unzip "$DIR/$BASE.zip" -d "$DIR/$BASE"
```

Put it in a file (anywhere), call it something like `unzipper.sh`, and `chmod a+x` it. Then you can call it like this:

```
/path/to/unzipper.sh /path/to/data_directory
```

Comment: You are commenting on everyone's answer, but you are not even providing a complete one yourself....

Comment: @iamauser: you'd prefer that I left incorrect answers uncontested? Or just anonymously downvoted? :)

Comment: rici, can you explain the position of this command inside the script?

Comment: @forensick: You need to figure out why you are not correctly identifying the zip file. The error message you pasted indicates that you're using `ZIP` rather than `zip`, which would definitely be an issue if the filename is `zip`. Or maybe it's the other way around.

Comment: @rici Your comment on the incorrect answer is justified, but I am not complaining about that. I was complaining about you didn't provide one while judging others...

Comment: @iamauser: well, go ahead and judge mine, then. I don't think it's about some aesthetic or moral sense of judgement though. The question is: does it work? If not, it should be fixed, because no-one wants SO to be a perpetual collection of bad answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
for zfile in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.zip")
do
  fn=$(echo ${zfile:2:4})  # this will give you the filename without .zip extension
  mkdir -p "$fn"  
  unzip "$zfile" -d "$fn"
done
```

Comment: `$(find . -type f -name "*.zip")` will search all subdirectories for zipfiles, which wasn't part of the original problem. Also, it will return results like `./F143.zip` (or `./subdirectory/F143.zip`) so `fn` will be set to garbage like `./F1`.)  And you invocation of `unzip` is wrong: `-d` specifies the directory to unzip into.

Comment: If it's correct to put the script in the same folder as the file, then it terminal gives "find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."

Comment: OK, although I still think you might as well just say `for zfile in *.zip; do`, which will be (somewhat) less quirky.

Comment: @user2809595 I have corrected before you commented that... I have swapped `maxdepth and type`

Comment: Oh, didn't see that :). Maybe now i m doing something wrong. The script is on the same folder with zip file, terminal also and i just run ./yourscript.sh, but nothing happens. Sorry for any mistake

Comment: As rici corrected me, now with the change from .zip to .ZIP, it seems to work! I will test it more. Two questions though. 1)If i want the script to be in a different folder,which the part that i modify to point to the data folder? 2) Can you please a brief explanation of the script?

Answer (score 0):

simple one liner I use all the time

```
$ for file in `ls *.zip`; do unzip $file -d `echo $file | cut -d . -f 1`; done
```

Comment: Parsing `ls` won't work for files with spaces. Your `$file` also missing the double quote.